# How to upload image without using or by hiding <input type='file' />?

Tags: php, html, ajax, upload, image-uploading

I am making a php script in which, I fetch the listing of directories and files from the targeted local computer drives.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is, when I click on particular image name from the listing, it suppose to upload to my server.

I don't want to select the image using "browse / input type='file'" button.

I tried several ways but not succeeded yet.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.
H Gandhi

Comment: it means you want to upload image to server by just selecting image from local machine.

Comment: You can't do that due to security reasons. You can upload only the files, that was selected by user.

Comment: You has to use file input. If you do not want to show the input you can hide it.

Comment: @TarangP, shukshin.ivan, Nirali Joshi. Thank you all for quick reply. suggest how to hide the <input type='file'> and at the same time set value to it without using form.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input').click();
});
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="somename" size="chars">
<button>Choose File Button</button>
```